# Support needed for preg_replace to detect language tag and remove other language data

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pattern-matching, str-replace

I have a data string which contains 3 different language content enclosed in corresponding tags.

`/[langStart-en]` and  `//[langEnd-en]` for English

`/[langStart-ar]` and  `//[langEnd-ar]` for Arabic

`/[langStart-fr]` and  `//[langEnd-fr]` for French

A language code will be passed as parameter through the url, say for 
eg. if the language is English, the url will be

`article.php?lang = EN`,

for Arabic `article.php?lang = AR` and

for French `article.php?lang = FR`.

I want to detect the Language and remove the contents for other languages from the string.

Hope this make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a quick solution for you. Please check if it works.. You should be able to optimize the logic, but I hope this will help you to make it working.

```
$pattern1 = '/\/\/\[langStart-en\][^n]*\/\/\[langEnd-en\]/';
$pattern2 = '/\/\/\[langStart-ar\][^n]*\/\/\[langEnd-ar\]/';
$pattern3 = '/\/\/\[langStart-fr\][^n]*\/\/\[langEnd-fr\]/';

$lan= $_GET['lang'];
$replace= '';
$string = "whatever may be string";

if ($lan=='EN')
{
$string = preg_replace($pattern2, $replace, $string);
$string = preg_replace($pattern3, $replace, $string);

}

else if ($lan=='AR')
{
$string = preg_replace($pattern1, $replace, $string);
$string = preg_replace($pattern3, $replace, $string);

}

else if ($lan=='FR')
{
$string = preg_replace($pattern1, $replace, $string);
$string = preg_replace($pattern2, $replace, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

Please check and let me know if you find any issues.

Answer (score 1):

For pattern matching, you may also use

```
$pattern1 = '/\/\/\[langStart-en\].+\/\/\[langEnd-en\]/';
```

The same can also be achieved by str.replace. You should be using

```
str.replace(/\/\/\[langStart-en\].+\/\/\[langEnd-en\]/, '//[langStart-en]//[langEnd-en]');
```

You should be trying this only if the above answer doesn't help